# How to cover a gap between doors and hardwood floor?

Tags: doors, interior

Removing old carpet resulted in about 1 inch gap between doors and the floor. What are common solutions to cover such gap? Any "easy to handle" materials (other than wood planks) to extend doors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to install some weather stripping to cover the gap. I realize it's indoors but this will be easy to install and work with, and will accomplish your goal.  Something like this:

[image: Weather Stripping]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/CR1O217_4.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It's hard to see from the picture, is this a foam based? How it is attached? OK, I guess I'd have to search for "weather stripping" at Home Depot.. Thanks!

Comment: It has rubber at the bottom. It attaches with a couple screws into the door

Answer (score 4):

The most common solution is to add "wood planks" to the floor, not the door. These are called saddles.  They are specialized moldings, usually about 3 to 6 inches wide with tapered edges. The usually are 1/2 to 3/4 inches thick.  They are centered under the door and reduce airflow and noise.

These are most commonly available in unfinished oak or pine:

[image: saddle]

They also can be found in other woods, prefinished, or matched to a floor system:

[image]