# How to cover gaps between hardwood floor and bottom of door frame

Tags: flooring, interior

After my floor tiles have been replaced by hardwood floor I have a gap underneath every door frame that is about 5mm (see picture). How is this usually covered?

I am looking for answers that consider aesthetics, as well as possible problems (moisture, pests, ...).

[image]

[image]

I consider the question [How to cover a gap between doors and hardwood floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15617/how-to-cover-a-gap-between-doors-and-hardwood-floor) different, as this gap is only 5mm and could possibly be covered using some kind of silicone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that it isn't usually "fixed" by inserting something in that gap. Ideally there would have been an underlayment installed to bring the new flooring up to the level of the old, but I can see why that effort and expense would be foregone.

Just about anything you'd put in there will make the situation more conspicuous and possibly create more nooks for dust and dirt to accumulate. From an aesthetic standpoint I think I'd gently scrape away the caulk or whatever's on the door trim and call it done.

I'm not sure why you feel like you need to seal between interior rooms in your home--every door in mine has about a 1" gap under it anyway. If you do, here are some ideas...

- Rope caulk: foam bead or plastic tubing that you'd insert under the trim, following its shape.
- Custom-cut plastic or vinyl plates that match the shape of the trim profile. I'm really not sure how you'd make or procure these, but maybe someone with a 3D printer could help. You'd secure them with something like silicone caulk as an adhesive.
- Simple rectangular plates of plastic or vinyl, sized to the outer dimensions of the trim.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is any one answer for how is it usually covered.

It really depends on budget, taste and how perfect you want it.  I think there are a number of options.

1. Leave as is
2. Use a plinth block for the casing sides, ignore the door jamb portion.  The casing side is typically the most visible.
3. #2 but also cut a piece of wood for the jamb portions that will fit the gap, glue, wood fill, sand and paint (the jamb is paint grade so should be possible to get that to look good ).
4. Redo casings and do #3 for the jambs.

I'd probably go for #3 and just gradually tackle over time.